# For the hyperbola $9x^2 - 4y^2 =36$, identify the vertices, foci, and asymptotes, then graph

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I don't know how to go about this question; an explanation going through the process of finding the vertices, foci, and asymptotes would be helpful.

$9x^{2}-4y^{2}=36$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the given equation as :

$$\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{9}=1$$

Now compare the given equation with standard hyperbola : $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ **(Notice $a<b$)**

Now,

**Foci** : $(\pm ae,0)$ ( Here $e$ is the eccenticity of hyperbola, given by $e^2=1+\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}$)

**Vertices** : $(\pm a,0)$

And the **Asymptotes** equation is given by : $$y = \pm \frac{b}{a} x$$

You can proceed now.

Comment: Would the explanation be the same as you had written it previously if a > b?

Comment: @Bazfred For $a<b$ - This answer; For $a>b$ my previous answer.