# Find the vertex, focus, and directrix of the parabola $y^2+2y+12x-23=0$

Tags: calculus

I feel I am doing the problem correctly however my answers are not following the solution.

My attempt:

$y^{2}+2y+12x-23=0$

$(y^{2}+2y+1) +12x = 23-1$

$(y+1)^{2}+12x=22$

$\dfrac{(y+1)^{2}}{22}+\dfrac{6x}{11}=1$

Note $a > b$

$a^{2}=22$

$b^{2}=11$

$c^{2}= 22-11$

$c= ± \sqrt{11}$

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, but the answers are supposed to be:

vertex: $(2,-1)$

focus: $(-1,-1)$

directrix: $x=5$

Comment: The mistake is in the RHS of the second line itself, You are adding $1$ to both sides, so it should be $23 \color{red}{+}1 = 24$

Comment: If you find any answer useful, please accept the best answer [See : How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as :
$(y+1)^2 = -12(x-2)$
So your vertex is (2,-1) focus is (-1,-1) and directrix : y= 5

Comment: You did something wrong, here $4a=-12 \implies a=-3$

Comment: ^@JaideepKhare I'm sorry was half asleep.

Answer (score 0):

[That Hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250582/for-the-hyperbola-9x2-4y2-36-identify-the-vertices-foci-and-asymptotes) Logic cannot be applied here.

For a parabola :

$$(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$$

**Vertex** is $(h,k)$

**Focus** is $(h+a,k)$

**Directrix** is $y=h-a$

Now compare this with your parabola : $$(y+1)^2 = -12(x-2)$$ To get $h=2 ; k=-1 ; a=\color{red}-3$. Now you may proceed.